# Playing sounds using javascript with multiple windows open

Tags: javascript, audio

I have a messaging system that plays a sound when a message is received, the messages are received in real time and all open windows receive each message. How can I have only one window play the sound or at least not have all of the windows combine their sounds, with more than one open it is very loud.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the function check a variable in `localStorage`

For example:

```
function PlaySound()
{
 if(localStorage.getItem("playing"))return;
 localStorage.setItem("playing",true)
 //...
}
function SoundEnd()
{
 localStorage.removeItem("playing");
}
```